# Can't use observableArrayList as value of hashmap in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I am trying to create a hashmap of a generic type to an array list type from FX Collections.

```
private val items = FXCollections.observableArrayList<T>()

private val itemsData = hashMapOf<T, FXCollections.observableArrayList<ItemData<T>>>()
```

The first line works fine, the second gives me a red line under 'observableArrayList'.

`Unresolved reference: observableArrayList`

This also works fine:

`private val itemsData = hashMapOf<T, ItemData<T>>()`

I'm new to kotlin and javafx, but even if importing observableArrayList directly doesn't help..

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing a `type` with an `object`.

`FXCollections.observableArrayList` is a method that returns an `instance` of `type` `ObservableList<E>`. The declaration of the `HashMap` needs a `type` in the generics though.

Give this a try:

```
val itemsData = hashMapOf<T, ObservableList<ItemData<T>>>();
```

A simpler example as an explaination:

```
// delcare that my password storage has a string type as key and a string type as value
val myPasswords = hashMapOf<String, String>();

// add a pair of string instances
myPasswords["stackoverflow.com"] = "topsecret"
```

Comment: @Adam.bocco if this answers the question, please also tag it as an answer ;) gives the community points for answering and also other people having the same issue will have a higher chance of finding this.